# cannot run forever in sudo centos8

Tags: centos

I installed forever in centos with

```
sudo npm install forever -g
```

i can run forever normally with

```
forever list
```

but when i run the same with

```
sudo forever list
```

it gives me this error

`forever command not found`

And i can only run forever in sudo mode by giving the absolute path of forever

like

```
sudo /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/forever list
```

can someone please help me in this matter?

Answer (score 1):

The command isn't recognized because the shell isn't searching its directory when looking for commands/binaries. You need to add `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/bin` to your PATH.

Put this line in `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/bin:$PATH
```

And then start a new shell session either by logging out and back in or opening a new terminal.

Comment: is this fix permanent?

Comment: @Mukund Yes. Why don't you try it and see? I suggest you do some research on shell init scripts.

Comment: i did the same but it didnt work so i created a link from `/usr/bin/`

Comment: There is no reason that it wouldn't work. Add the contents of `~/.bashrc` and `echo $PATH` to your question and make sure that you are starting a new shell session.